# Can't access bing maps service api (windows phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, bing-maps

I'm developing universal app in C#.
I have next url which works on tablet project, but for windows phone project doesn't:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied
```

I am using next key for wp (works with MapControl):

Key type: Basic / Public Windows Phone App   //i have also tried trial key without success

Created date: my creation date

Expiration date: None

```
var url = string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/{0}/{2},{3}/{4}?key={1}&mapSize=500,500",
                imagery, mapKey, Math.Round(latitude, 5), Math.Round(longtitude, 5), zoom);
```

Why can't I use this service from phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps REST Service uses a different key from the one used on the MapControl. The appID + token used for the MapControl are provided for Here, which provides the control and the data for the phones since WP8.0 (and of course later)

Simply said, you need to get the appropriate key from Bing Maps Account Center using a Microsoft Account (aka Live ID), to create your own key see: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx

Create the appropriate key using the dedicated section: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx

The Bing Maps Account Center is here: 
https://www.bingmapsportal.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please clarify which key type should i use for the service? Will it work for both platforms (wp/tablet)? Sorry but i couldn't find any info about key types.

Comment: AppId and token you have generated on the Windows Store is for the WP8 MapControl ; Bing Maps key are for using REST services + WP7 Control + Other MapControls (AJAX, Silverlight, WPF...)